# eclipse: close all referencing projects

Tags: eclipse

Is there a way to force eclipse to close all projects that reference the current project?  Sometimes when working on a base project, I don't want to force it to build all the referencing projects, so I close them out, but that can get tedious with a dozen or more projects that reference the base.

It would also be nice to have a setting that closes all referencing projects when I close the base.

Comment: You can always just turn automatic building off (Project > Build Automatically).

Comment: @greg-449 I know.  That's what I have right now, but I was hoping there was a way to do this rather than using a workaround